# "value of type 'Set<UITouch>' has no member 'AnyObject'" in touchesBegan()

Tags: ios, swift

When I try to run this statement using Xcode 7, Swift 2:

```
lastpoint = touches.AnyObject().locationInView(self)
```

it gives an error

> "value of type 'Set' has no member 'AnyObject'"

Why?

Answer (score 1):

There is no `AnyObject` method if `Set`.  `NSSet` has `anyObject`, but `touchesBegan` method now uses Swift `Set` rather than foundation `NSSet`.

Nowadays you might do:

```
if let location = touches.first?.locationInView(self) { ... }
```